# Combination of N ordered element

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a set of K element and i need to create a combination of N ordered element.
For examle if K=1 and i have {X1, emptyset} and n = 2 then i have an ordered pair i need to make this:

**Example1:**

```
 ({},{})  
 ({X1},{}), ({},{X1})  
 ({X1},{X1})
```

Note that I need to get the element in this order: first the element with 0 node as the sum of both pairs, second the element with 1, ecc

My idea is to make the set of parts of the intial set, adding an element at time, but I'm losing my mind. Any suggestions? I need to do this in java.

**EDIT 1:**
In other words I need to create an Hasse diagram:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram

where every node is an element of the set of parts and the partial-ordering function is the inclusion of on all the subset like this:

**Example2:**

ni = (S1i,S2i) C nj = (S1j,S2j) only if S1i C S1j AND S21 C s2j

**EDIT2: @RONALD:**

If I have K=2 for a set S = {1, 2} and n =2, i need this output:

```
 level0: ({}, {})  
 level1: ({1}, {}); ({2}, {}); ({}, {1}); ({}, {2})  
 level2: ({1,2}, {}); ({1}, {1}); ({1}, {2}); ({2}, {1}); ({2}, {2}); ({}, {1,2});   
 [..]
```

the order is important between levels, for example:

If at level1 i have

```
 ({1}, {}); ({2}, {}); ({}, {1}); ({}, {2})
```

OR

```
 ({}, {2}); ({}, {1}); ({2}, {}); ({1}, {});
```

is the same thing. But it's importat that at level 2 i have all superset of level2 and a superset is explained in **example 2**

**EDIT3:**
If my set is S= {x,y,z} and i have only one set per node the result (**starting from the bottom**) is this:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg

If I have S={1,2} and two set per nod the result is this (thanks Ronald for the diagram) :
http://www.independit.de/Downloads/hasse.pdf

**EDIT4:**

Because is a super-exponential problem my idea is: I compute one level at time (in ordered mode!) and with some rule i prune a node and all his superset. Another stop rule may be to stop at a certain level. For this rule it is essential to calculate combinations directly in an orderly manner **and not** to calculate all and then reorder.

**EDIT5:**

The Marco13's code work fine, i have make some modify for:

- Use function PowerSet because it's helpfull for make all combination of only K element of a set S (I only need to get the first tot element of powerset for do this).

Now the algorithm do all but i need to speed up it. Is there any way to parallelize the computation? such a way to use Map Reduce (Apache hadoop implementation) paradigm?

```
package utilis;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class HasseDiagramTest4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numberOfSetsPerNode = 3;

        List<Integer> set = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6);
        List<Set<Integer>> powerSet = computePowerSet(set);
        powerSet = KPowerSet(powerSet, 3);

        List<List<Set<Integer>>> prunedNodes = 
            new ArrayList<List<Set<Integer>>>();
        List<Set<Integer>> prunedNode = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();

        HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
        HashSet<Integer> s_vuoto = new HashSet<Integer>();
        s.add(1);
        s.add(2);
        prunedNode.add(s);
        prunedNode.add(s_vuoto);
        prunedNode.add(s);

       prunedNodes.add(prunedNode);

        compute(ordina(powerSet), numberOfSetsPerNode, prunedNodes);
    }

    private static <T> HashMap<Integer, List<Set<T>>> ordina(List<Set<T>> powerSet) {

        HashMap<Integer, List<Set<T>>> hs = new HashMap<Integer, List<Set<T>>>();

        for(Set<T> l: powerSet)
        {
            List<Set<T>> lput = new  ArrayList<Set<T>>();
            if(hs.containsKey(l.size()))
            {
                lput = hs.get(l.size());
                lput.add(l);
                hs.put(l.size(), lput);
            }
            else
            {
                lput.add(l);
                hs.put(l.size(), lput); 
            }

        }

        return hs;
    }

    private static <T> List<Set<T>> KPowerSet(List<Set<T>> powerSet, int k)
    {
        List<Set<T>> result = new ArrayList<Set<T>>();

        for(Set<T>s:powerSet)
        {
            if(s.size() <= k)
            {
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static <T> List<Set<T>> computePowerSet(List<T> set)
    {
        List<Set<T>> result = new ArrayList<Set<T>>();
        int numElements = 1 << set.size();
        for (int j=0; j<numElements; j++)
        {
            Set<T> element = new HashSet<T>();
            for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++)
            {
                long b = 1 << i;
                if ((j & b) != 0)
                {
                    element.add(set.get(i));
                }
            }
            result.add(element);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<Integer> createList(int numberOfElements)
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            list.add(i+1);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static <T> void compute(
            HashMap<Integer, List<Set<T>>> powerSet, int numberOfSetsPerNode,
        List<List<Set<T>>> prunedNodes)
    {
        Set<List<Set<T>>> level0 = createLevel0(numberOfSetsPerNode);
        System.out.println("Level 0:");
        print(level0);

        Set<List<Set<T>>> currentLevel = level0;
        int level = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Set<List<Set<T>>> nextLevel = 
                createNextLevel(currentLevel, powerSet, prunedNodes);
            if (nextLevel.size() == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Next level: "+nextLevel.size()+" nodes");
            print(nextLevel);

            currentLevel = nextLevel;
            level++;
        }
    }

    private static <T> Set<List<Set<T>>> createLevel0(int numberOfSetsPerNode)
    {
        Set<List<Set<T>>> level0 = 
            new LinkedHashSet<List<Set<T>>>();
        List<Set<T>> level0element = new ArrayList<Set<T>>();
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfSetsPerNode; i++)
        {
            level0element.add(new LinkedHashSet<T>());
        }
        level0.add(level0element);
        return level0;
    }

    private static <T> List<Set<T>> getNext(Set<T> current, HashMap<Integer, List<Set<T>>> powerSet)
    {
        ArrayList<Set<T>> ritorno = new ArrayList<Set<T>>(); 
        int level = current.size();
        List<Set<T>> listnext = powerSet.get(level+1);

        if(listnext != null)
        {
            for(Set<T> next: listnext)
            {
                if(next.containsAll(current))
                {
                    ritorno.add(next);
                }
            }
        }

        return ritorno;
    }


    private static <T> Set<List<Set<T>>> createNextLevel(
        Set<List<Set<T>>> currentLevel, HashMap<Integer, List<Set<T>>> powerSet,
        List<List<Set<T>>> prunedNodes)
    {
        Set<List<Set<T>>> nextLevel = new LinkedHashSet<List<Set<T>>>();

        //Per ogni nodo del livello corrente
        for (List<Set<T>> currentLevelElement : currentLevel)
        {
            //Per ogni insieme del nodo preso in considerazione
            for (int i=0; i<currentLevelElement.size(); i++)
            {
                List<Set<T>> listOfnext = getNext (currentLevelElement.get(i), powerSet);


                for (Set<T> element : listOfnext)
                {
                    List<Set<T>> nextLevelElement = copy(currentLevelElement);
                    Set<T> next = element;
                    nextLevelElement.remove(i);
                    nextLevelElement.add(i, next);

                    boolean pruned = false;
                    for (List<Set<T>> prunedNode : prunedNodes)
                    {
                        if (isSuccessor(prunedNode, nextLevelElement))
                        {
                            pruned = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!pruned)
                    {
                        nextLevel.add(nextLevelElement);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Pruned "+nextLevelElement+ " due to "+prunedNodes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nextLevel;
    }

    private static <T> boolean isSuccessor(
        List<Set<T>> list, List<Set<T>> successor)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            Set<T> set = list.get(i);
            Set<T> successorSet = successor.get(i);
            //System.out.println("Successor:" + successorSet + "pruned:" + set);
            if (!successorSet.containsAll(set))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static <T> List<Set<T>> copy(List<Set<T>> list)
    {
        List<Set<T>> result = new ArrayList<Set<T>>();
        for (Set<T> element : list)
        {
            result.add(new LinkedHashSet<T>(element));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static <T> void print(
        Iterable<? extends Collection<? extends Collection<T>>> sequence)
    {
        for (Collection<? extends Collection<T>> collections : sequence)
        {
            System.out.println("    "+collections);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: looks like counting (k+1)-ary (in your example binary) into a number with n digits?

Comment: I need to create an Hasse diagram where every node is an element of the set of parts and the partial-ordering function is the inclusion of on all the subset like this: ni = (S1i,S2i) C nj = (S1j,S2j) only if S1i C S1j AND S21 C s2j

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly but the "Collections2" and "Sets" classes is google's guava package might be very helpful here.  Collections2 makes getting ordered permutations easy and Sets provides methods like powerSet, cartiesianProduct, union, intersection...  see: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Sets.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't know what you actually want. Specify the ordering of the resulting tuples of subsets. Based on the current definition, the statement `({2}, {}) < ({1}, {1})` would **not** hold, but still, the first one should be in level1, and the second one should be in level2.

Comment: Because at level 1 we have all nodes with 1 element example ({2}, {}). At elevel 2 with 2 element example ({1}, {1}). I knwo what i want, it's just hard to explain.

Comment: Concerning EDIT5: One place where you could start a parallelization could be the loop `//Per ogni nodo del livello corrente`: This could be handled by a tread pool, with some precautions (e.g. `nextLevel` would have to be a `ConcurrentHashMap` etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 4 EDITs and a lot of discussion, it's slowly becoming more clear what the goal of this application is. Indeed, one would have to think about an appropriate formalization, but it finally does not seem to be so difficult.

In contrast to my first answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092523 ) this new one iteratively computes the next level from the previous level (and the core of this, `createNextLevel`, is just 10 lines of code).

In the `compute` method, the pruning that was asked for in "EDIT4" could be integrated into the `while` loop.

EDIT: Still more requests in the comments. Integrated them. But this is becoming ridiculous. Um den Rest kannst du dich selbst kümmern.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class HasseDiagramTest2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numberOfElements = 2;
        int numberOfSetsPerNode = 2;

        List<Integer> list = createList(numberOfElements);

        List<List<Set<Integer>>> prunedNodes = 
            new ArrayList<List<Set<Integer>>>();
        List<Set<Integer>> prunedNode = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
        prunedNode.add(Collections.singleton(1));
        prunedNode.add(Collections.singleton(1));
        prunedNodes.add(prunedNode);

        compute(list, numberOfSetsPerNode, prunedNodes);
    }

    private static List<Integer> createList(int numberOfElements)
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            list.add(i+1);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static <T> void compute(
        List<T> elements, int numberOfSetsPerNode,
        List<List<Set<T>>> prunedNodes)
    {
        Set<List<Set<T>>> level0 = createLevel0(numberOfSetsPerNode);
        System.out.println("Level 0:");
        print(level0);

        Set<List<Set<T>>> currentLevel = level0;
        int level = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Set<List<Set<T>>> nextLevel = 
                createNextLevel(currentLevel, elements, prunedNodes);
            if (nextLevel.size() == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Next level: "+nextLevel.size()+" nodes");
            print(nextLevel);

            currentLevel = nextLevel;
            level++;
        }
    }

    private static <T> Set<List<Set<T>>> createLevel0(int numberOfSetsPerNode)
    {
        Set<List<Set<T>>> level0 = 
            new LinkedHashSet<List<Set<T>>>();
        List<Set<T>> level0element = new ArrayList<Set<T>>();
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfSetsPerNode; i++)
        {
            level0element.add(new LinkedHashSet<T>());
        }
        level0.add(level0element);
        return level0;
    }

    private static <T> Set<List<Set<T>>> createNextLevel(
        Set<List<Set<T>>> currentLevel, List<T> elements,
        List<List<Set<T>>> prunedNodes)
    {
        Set<List<Set<T>>> nextLevel = new LinkedHashSet<List<Set<T>>>();
        for (List<Set<T>> currentLevelElement : currentLevel)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<currentLevelElement.size(); i++)
            {
                for (T element : elements)
                {
                    List<Set<T>> nextLevelElement = copy(currentLevelElement);
                    Set<T> next = nextLevelElement.get(i);
                    boolean changed = next.add(element);
                    if (!changed)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    boolean pruned = false;
                    for (List<Set<T>> prunedNode : prunedNodes)
                    {
                        if (isSuccessor(prunedNode, nextLevelElement))
                        {
                            pruned = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!pruned)
                    {
                        nextLevel.add(nextLevelElement);
                    }
                    else
                    {
//                        System.out.println(
//                            "Pruned "+nextLevelElement+
//                            " due to "+prunedNodes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nextLevel;
    }

    private static <T> boolean isSuccessor(
        List<Set<T>> list, List<Set<T>> successor)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            Set<T> set = list.get(i);
            Set<T> successorSet = successor.get(i);
            if (!successorSet.containsAll(set))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static <T> List<Set<T>> copy(List<Set<T>> list)
    {
        List<Set<T>> result = new ArrayList<Set<T>>();
        for (Set<T> element : list)
        {
            result.add(new LinkedHashSet<T>(element));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static <T> void print(
        Iterable<? extends Collection<? extends Collection<T>>> sequence)
    {
        for (Collection<? extends Collection<T>> collections : sequence)
        {
            System.out.println("    "+collections);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Good but for the pruning method there is a problem. You make nextlevel by taking one element at time from the current level. Get thisdiagram: http://www.independit.de/Downloads/hasse.pdf If i need to delete node ({1}, {1}) and all his offspring that is ({1}, {1,2}) , {1,2}, {1}) AND ({1,2}, {1,2}) I need that none of other node generate these nodes. It's not simple.

Comment: @Neptune Added an EDIT. Asking questions precisely is an art, and stackoverflow is not a way of outsourcing your programming tasks to volunteers. Keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: I am truly grateful for everyone's help. I apologize if I was not clear enough at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a basic set `S = {1, 2}`, then `K = 2` and the set of subsets of S is `{{}, {1}, {2}, {1,2}}`. Assume *n* is still 2. Then your output will be something like

```
({}, {})
({1}, {}); ({2}, {}); ({}, {1}); ({}, {2})
({1,2}, {});          ({}, {1,2})
({1}, {1}); ({1}, {2}); ({2}, {1}); ({2}, {2})
({1}, {1,2}); ({1,2}, {1}); ({2}, {1,2}); ({1,2}, {2})
({1,2}, {1,2})
```

Correct? The ordering with the output is a bit difficult because the result isn't fully ordered. But it still boils down to counting. Not, as I initially thought, (K+1)-ary but more (2^K)-ary.

In order to determine if one set is a subset of another, using primes might be an idea.
You assign a prime number to each element of your original set. In my example, that would be 2 and 3. The set of subsets can be build by generating all products of the prime numbers. In my example that would be `{1 /* empty set */, 2, 3, 6}`.
If you have two sets, represented by your product it is easy to test the inclusion:

```
if (a % b == 0) then b is a subset of a
```

It's just a bunch of ideas, but they might help you finding a solution. Of course, the prime trick only works for a relatively small number of elements in your original set, but as soon as K and N grow, you'll get problems anyway. (The number of elements in your output will be `(2^K)^N = 2^(NK)`. If `K == N == 5`, you'll have `2^(5 * 5) = 2^25`, about 32 million output elements. And here the prime thought still works).

Edit: Well I wrote a small Java Program to show my ideas.

1. save it to Hasse.java
2. compile it: `javac Hasse.java`
3. run it: `java Hasse > hasse.dot`
4. run dot: `dot -Tpdf -ohasse.pdf hasse.dot`
5. view it: `acroread hasse.pdf`

Source Code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Hasse {

        private static int K[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
        private static int N   = 2;
        private static int prime[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97 };
        //
        // PK[0][] is the array of "subsets"
        // PK[1][] is the array of number of elements of K participating in the subset
        //
        private static int PK[][];

        // some constants; the initialization is clear enough
        private static final long twoNK = pow(2, N * K.length);
        private static final int twoK = (int) pow(2, K.length);
        private static final int  NK = N * K.length;
        private static final long NKf = fac(NK);

        //
        // this power function isn't suitable for large powers
        // but in the range we are working, it's OK
        //
        public static long pow(int b, int p)
        {
                long result = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
                        result *= b;

                return result;
        }

        // fac calculates n! (needed for the a over b calculation)
        public static long fac(int n)
        {
                long result = 1;
                for (int i = n; i > 0; --i) result *= i;

                return result;
        }

        //
        // constructPK builds the set of subsets of K
        // a subset is represented by a product of primes
        // each element k_i of K has an associated prime p_i
        // since the prime factorization of a number is unique,
        // the product can be translated into a subset and vice versa
        //
        public static void constructPK()
        {
                int i, cnt;
                int numElms = twoK;
                PK = new int[2][numElms];

                for (i = 0; i < numElms; ++i) {
                        int j = i;
                        cnt = 0;
                        PK[0][i] = 1;
                        PK[1][i] = 0;
                        while (j > 0) {
                                if (j % 2 == 1) {
                                        PK[0][i] *= prime[cnt];
                                        PK[1][i]++;
                                }
                                cnt++;
                                j /= 2;
                        }
                }
        }

        // we have a k-ary number (that is: binary if k == 2, octal if k == 8
        // and so on
        // the addOne() function calculates the next number based on the input
        public static void addOne(int kAry[])
        {
                int i = 0;

                kAry[i] += 1;
                while (kAry[i] >= twoK) {
                        kAry[i] = 0;
                        ++i;
                        kAry[i] += 1;
                }
        }

        // the addN() function is similar to the addOne() function
        // with the difference that it add n to the input, not just 1
        public static void addN(int kAry[], int n)
        {
                int i = 0;

                kAry[i] += n;
                for (i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i) {
                        while (kAry[i] >= twoK) {
                                kAry[i] -= twoK;
                                kAry[i+1] += 1;
                        }
                }
        }

        // from the k-ary number, which represents a node in the graph,
        // the "level" is calculated.
        public static int getLevel(int kAry[])
        {
                int level = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                        level += PK[1][kAry[i]];
                }
                return level;
        }

        // output function for a node
        public static String renderNode(int kAry[])
        {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String sep = "";

                sb.append("(");
                for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                        String setSep = "";
                        int p = PK[0][kAry[i]];
                        sb.append(sep);
                        sb.append("{");
                        for (int j = 0; j < K.length; ++j) {
                                if (p % prime[j] == 0) {
                                        sb.append(setSep + K[j]);
                                        setSep = ", ";
                                }
                        }
                        sb.append("}");
                        sep = ", ";
                }
                sb.append(")");

                return sb.toString();
        }

        // This function calculates the numerical representation
        // of a node, addressed by its level and position within the level,
        // in the k-ary number system
        // if there's a more elegant way of finding the node, it would 
        // largely speed up the calculation, since this function is needed
        // for calculating the edges
        public static int[] getKAry(int level, int node)
        {
                int kAry[] = new int[N];
                int nodesSoFar = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) kAry[i] = 0;

                for (int cnt = 0; cnt < twoNK; ++cnt) {
                        if (getLevel(kAry) == level) {
                                if (nodesSoFar == node) {
                                        return kAry;
                                } else
                                        nodesSoFar++;
                        }
                        if (cnt + 1 < twoNK)
                                addOne(kAry);
                }
                return null;
        }

        // this function converts the decimal nodeNumber to
        // its k-ary representation
        public static int[] getKAry(int nodeNumber)
        {
                int kAry[] = new int[N];

                for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) kAry[i] = 0;

                addN(kAry, nodeNumber);

                return kAry;
        }

        public static String getLabel(int level, int node)
        {
                int kAry[] = getKAry(level, node);

                return (kAry == null ? "Oops!" : renderNode(kAry));
        }

        public static void printPK()
        {
                System.out.println("# Number of elements: " + PK[0].length);
                for (int i = 0; i < PK[0].length; ++i) {
                        System.out.println("# PK[0][" + i + "] = " + PK[0][i] + ",\tPK[1][" + i + "] = " + PK[1][i]);
                }
        }

        public static void printPreamble()
        {
                System.out.println("digraph G {");
                System.out.println("ranksep = 3");
                System.out.println();
        }

        public static void printEnd()
        {
                System.out.println("}");
        }

        public static void printNodes()
        {
                int numNodes;

                for (int i = 0; i <= NK; ++i) {
                        int level = i + 1;
                        numNodes = (int) (NKf / (fac(i) * fac(NK - i)));
                        for (int j = 0; j < numNodes; ++j) {
                                System.out.println("level_" + level + "_" + (j+1) + " [shape=box,label=\"" + getLabel(i, j) + "\"];");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println();
        }

        // having two vectors of "sets", this function determines
        // if each set in the ss (small set) vector is a subset of
        // the corresponding set in the ls (large set) vector
        public static boolean isSubset(int ss[], int ls[])
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                        if (PK[0][ls[i]] % PK[0][ss[i]] != 0) return false;
                return true;
        }

        // this function finds and prints the edges
        // it is called about twoNK times (once for each node)
        // therefore performance optimizations have to be done here
        public static void printEdges(int level, int node, int nodeNumber)
        {
                int kAry[] = getKAry(node);
                int nlAry[];
                int numNodes = (int) (NKf / (fac(level + 1) * fac(NK - level - 1)));
                String myNode = "level_" + (level + 1) + "_" + (node + 1);

                for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; ++i) {
                        nlAry = getKAry(level + 1, i);
                        if (nlAry == null) System.exit(1);
                        if (isSubset(kAry, nlAry)) {
                                System.out.println(myNode + " -> level_" + (level + 2) + "_" + (i + 1));
                        }
                }
        }

        // this function renders the dot file
        // first some initial text (preamble),
        // then the nodes and the edges
        // and finally the closing brace
        public static void renderDot()
        {
                int numNodes;
                int nodeNumber = 0;

                printPreamble();
                printNodes();
                for (int level = 0; level < NK; ++level) {
                        numNodes = (int) (NKf / (fac(level) * fac(NK - level)));
                        for (int node = 0; node < numNodes; ++node) {
                                // find the edges to the nodes on the next level
                                printEdges(level, node, nodeNumber);
                                ++nodeNumber;
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }
                printEnd();
        }

        public static void main (String argv[])
        {
                constructPK();
                renderDot();
        }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that I put "level 2" in two lines (line 3 and 4) I seem to have understood the targeted result. A drawing of the output above can be found at [http://www.independit.de/Downloads/hasse.pdf](http://www.independit.de/Downloads/hasse.pdf), the dot source is under [http://www.independit.de/Downloads/hasse.dot](http://www.independit.de/Downloads/hasse.dot). I think it isn't magic to generate the dot source. If I find the time, I'll give it a try.
Note: the dot source isn't a word template file, it's plain text.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! But i have a problem, if my is K[] = { 1, 2, 3,4 } and N is 10 i need to generete more prime number? how many? here is a method to calculate them automatically in the code? i have not understood why the prime number.

Comment: Ok i have understood the "primary number method" remain the problem of automatically generete the prime number. Can I ask you  to add comments to your code?

Comment: If i put N=8 for example the algoritm don't compute all level but the prime number is only one for node and i don't edit the number of node.

Comment: If you have "large" N and |K|, the program tries to calculate `2^(N*K)` which easily exceeds the capacity of an int. The number of primes needed is |K|, so with the first 25 primes statically defined you have plenty of room. But it shouldn't be a problem to write a small function that dynamically calculates the primes needed. If you start testing with "large" values, keep in mind that the number of nodes will be `2^(N*|K|)`. With `|K| = 4` and `N = 10`, you'll end up with `2^40` nodes, which is about `10^12`.

Comment: Since the complexity of my program is probably something like `O(2^(2*N*|K|))` the running time will also exceed every limit. It might be possible to speed it up by storing calculated values, but that will cost huge amounts of memory. Any other algorithm will at least have a complexity of `O(2^(N*|K|))` (the number of nodes generated, and since there are more edges than nodes ...). With the numbers you mentioned, you cannot make a graphical representation any more. You can't draw a billion nodes on a piece of paper.

Comment: I don't need to draw the graph. I use the graph to model the search space of an algorithm. My idea is: First I found a good algorithm; Second step I seeking a way to paralelized that on Hadoop (map/reduce); Third step I use pruning rules;

Comment: You say that the program exceeds the capacity of an int but i have no error! The program of  Marco13 works fine on k=3 and N=8 but your idea of prime number for the inclusion it's a good idea..

Comment: you won't get an error reported, the twoNK field will simply overflow and contain some number. If you make a long out of it, it'll fit, but you'll also have to signature of the pow() function (should return a long too). Still, the amount of data produced is HUGE, if |K| = 3 and N = 8. (16 million nodes and many more edges). I'll do some commenting in my source.

Comment: There is no solution for avoid overflow? Thanks for the comment, now i begin to well study your code.

Comment: as I wrote, with a `long` data type, you won't get overflow (until `N * K > 63`. But then we're talking about `10^19` nodes. It'll be hard to store them. Even if a node would occupy only 1 bit, you'd need 10^18 bytes, that's one billion gigabytes or a million terabytes. I have found a speed optimization that is easy to implement. The binomial coefficients can be calculated and stored. That substantially reduces the number of calls to fac().

Comment: But i have problem with K=3 and N=8, it's only 24. Now i have an error in code on twoK, is declared as an int but pow return long. I add a cast to int or.. ?

Comment: I suppos java make a problem if i make a matrix with dimension of long like PK = new int[2][numElms] where numElms is long. Then i suppos twoK is an int.

Comment: Yes, in the case of `twoK`, where `K < 32`, you'll have to cast it to an int. I forgot that as I modified the code. And it won't be a good idea to choose K large. Something in the range of 1 to 5 will be usable, I think. So you won't easily run into problems there.

Comment: A nice aspect of my code/algorithm is that you don't actually have to store the result. You can just choose some node and calculate its successors (and with some small modification of the successor method, also the predecessors). Another thought is that modifying the method of counting, in a way that there's a 1:1 map to the original sequence, but ordered according to the level, would speed up the determination of the k-ary array (or number in my perspective). This is done very often when calculating the edges, so it would show a huge impact.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, I'm rather sure that the formalization of *what* actually should be done is either unclear or plainly wrong. The criterion for comparing the "nodes" does not match the examples. However, once the sorting criterion (in form of a `Comparator`) has been specified, this should be rather easy to implement.

Here, the criterion for comparing two "nodes" is the sum of the sizes of all sets in the node, which matches the example that was given (although it intuitively does not make sense, because it does not correspond to any real subset relationship....)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class HasseDiagramTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> set = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
        List<List<Integer>> powerSet = computePowerSet(set);
        List<List<List<Integer>>> combinations = 
            computeCombinations(powerSet, 2);
        Comparator<List<List<Integer>>> comparator = createComparator();
        Collections.sort(combinations, comparator);
        List<List<List<List<Integer>>>> levels = createLevels(combinations);
        for (List<List<List<Integer>>> level : levels)
        {
            System.out.println(level);
        }
    }

    private static <T> List<List<List<List<T>>>> createLevels(
        List<List<List<T>>> sortedCombinations)
    {
        List<List<List<List<T>>>> levels = new ArrayList<List<List<List<T>>>>();
        int previousTotalSize = -1;
        List<List<List<T>>> currentLevel = null;
        for (int i=0; i<sortedCombinations.size(); i++)
        {
            List<List<T>> combination = sortedCombinations.get(i);
            int totalSize = totalSize(combination);
            if (previousTotalSize != totalSize)
            {
                previousTotalSize = totalSize;
                currentLevel = new ArrayList<List<List<T>>>();
                levels.add(currentLevel);
            }
            currentLevel.add(combination);
        }
        return levels;
    }


    private static <T> Comparator<List<List<T>>> createComparator()
    {
        return new Comparator<List<List<T>>>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(List<List<T>> list0, List<List<T>> list1)
            {
                return Integer.compare(totalSize(list0), totalSize(list1));
            }
        };
    }

    private static <T> int totalSize(List<List<T>> lists)
    {
        int totalSize = 0;
        for (List<T> list : lists)
        {
            totalSize += list.size();
        }
        return totalSize;
    }


    private static <T> List<List<T>> computePowerSet(List<T> set)
    {
        List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        int numElements = 1 << set.size();
        for (int j=0; j<numElements; j++)
        {
            List<T> element = new ArrayList<T>();
            for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++)
            {
                long b = 1 << i;
                if ((j & b) != 0)
                {
                    element.add(set.get(i));
                }
            }
            result.add(element);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static <T> List<List<T>> computeCombinations(List<T> list, int sampleSize)
    {
         int numElements = (int) Math.pow(list.size(), sampleSize);
         int chosen[] = new int[sampleSize];
         List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
         for (int current = 0; current < numElements; current++)
         {
             List<T> element = new ArrayList<T>(sampleSize);
             for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
             {
                 element.add(list.get(chosen[i]));
             }
             result.add(element);
             increase(chosen, list.size());
         }
         return result;
    }

    private static void increase(int chosen[], int inputSize)
    {
        int index = chosen.length - 1;
        while (index >= 0)
        {
            if (chosen[index] < inputSize - 1)
            {
                chosen[index]++;
                return;
            }
            chosen[index] = 0;
            index--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have test your solution but what i need to do to add more K or more N?

Comment: More elements: `Arrays.asList(1, 2, further elements go here);`. More elements per node: `computeCombinations(powerSet, numberOfElementsPerNode);`. But again: The ordering criterion is not clear. You might have to use a different `Comparator`, but as long as you don't specify the ordering criterion, it's difficult to figure this out...

Comment: If you imagine a Hasse diagram, you have more level like a Tree BUT a node can have more father. At level i you have al node with a total of i elements in all of N sets ok? In add you have edge only between actual level (es i) e next level (i+1). There is an edge between two node only if (look example 2). The result for K=2 and N=2 is the ronald graph at these adress: http://www.independit.de/Downloads/hasse.pdf

Comment: OK, when it is about the total number of elements, then my guess was correct. That's what is currently used in the code that I posted (but it has nothing to do with the definition of the ordering that you gave in the original question)

Comment: Among the various algorithms that I have to deal with the problem yours is the most fast. The problem is that, i need to make the node one level at time, first level 0, next level 1, etc for apply some pruning rule. If the algoritmh first make all nodes unordered and sorts them after i can't make pruning because i need to generete all nodes first.